# viewbox and icon positioning in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I just have this very simple svg below;

```
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 194 186" class="circliful">
  <g stroke="#ccc">
    <line x1="133" y1="50" x2="140" y2="40" stroke-width="2"></line>
  </g>
  <g stroke="#ccc">
    <line x1="140" y1="40" x2="200" y2="40" stroke-width="2"></line>
  </g>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" class="border" fill="#eee" stroke="none" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>
  <circle class="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="57" fill="none" stroke="#3498DB" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="180, 20000" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110" class="icon" style="font-size: 40px" fill="#3498DB"></text>
  <text class="timer" text-anchor="middle" x="175" y="35" style="font-size: 22px; undefined;" fill="#aaa">50%</text>
</svg>

</div>
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/wynhn1ds/4/)**

The viewbox of the svg element is `viewBox="0 0 194 300"` and the `y` attribute on the icon is `y="110"` , my question is , is the Y attibute intentionally `110` ??

I.E. if i wanted to center the icon i would do the following:

```
(186/2)+ (height of icon/2) // 186 is the height of the viewbox
```

Am i right in assuming that the value of 110 is added in respect to the height of the viewbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The y value of 110 will have been chosen by the author in order to vertically centre the text in the circle.  It is not directly related to the viewBox.  It is related to the centre of the circle, the size of the text (22) and to some extent the shape of the glyphs in whatever font is being used.  For instance, the height of capital letters may vary for different fonts given the same font size.

SVG does not provide any way to automatically centre text vertically.  So you have to position text manually.

Comment: so the major reason for choosing 110 is because the size of the circle is 100 ? and ofcourse the other reasons u mentioned !

Comment: Nothing to do with size of the circle.  It doesn't matter how big the circle is. Here the circle is 114 in diameter (radius=57).  But it could be 200 and the y coord wouldn't change.  The centre of the circle is at y=100. The font size is 22. So the baseline (y coord) of text would be at approx 100+(22/2) = 111.  Then maybe (as in this case) tweaked a bit due to the shape of the font.

Answer (score 0):

Nope

```
dominant-baseline="central"
x="100"
```

`100` is the vertical center of the circle (`ry` in the circle element) and `dominant-baseline` sets the text Y coordinate to the vertical center of the text.

Comment: yes i am aware of that trick , i am just talking in approximates .  :)

Comment: I just basically wanted to know that 110 was added there keeping in mind the height of the viewbox was 186 ! :)

Comment: The height of the viewbox in the jsfiddle is 300 :/

Comment: thats a mistake iám sorry ! so 110 has nothing to do with the viewbox height ?